# PHPMailer no sending, not giving errors throwing 500 error

Tags: php, email, openshift, phpmailer, sendgrid

UPDATE: This is the error I receive: SMTP connect() failed.
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'SMTP connect() failed.'

I am working with a pre-existing php framework called Frameworx. Everything was great, but it won't send the emails which I believe is because I am using OpenShift and they are strict about their mail server. I need to use SendGrid, so I was trying ot use PHPMailer to do this. Maybe I am going about this all wrong. But basically when I try and send the mail all I get is a blank page. User is created.

this is what I have:

```
        // Create a New Account Form
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'newAccount') {
        // User Validations
        if($_POST['usersName'] == '') {
            $msgBox = alertBox("Your First and Last Name is required.", "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
        } else if($_POST['usersEmail'] == '') {
            $msgBox = alertBox("A valid Email Address is required.", "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
        } else if($_POST['password'] == '') {
            $msgBox = alertBox("A New Account Password is required.", "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
        } else if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['passwordr']) {
            $msgBox = alertBox("Passwords do not match, please check your entries.", "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
        // Black Hole Trap to help reduce bot registrations
        } else if($_POST['captcha'] != '') {
            $msgBox = alertBox("An Error was encountered and the New Account could not be created.", "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
        } else {
            // Set some variables
            $dupEmail = '';
            $newEmail = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['usersEmail']);

            // Check for Duplicate email
            $check = $mysqli->query("SELECT 'X' FROM users WHERE usersEmail = '".$newEmail."'");
            if ($check->num_rows) {
                $dupEmail = 'true';
            }

            // If duplicates are found
            if ($dupEmail != '') {
                $msgBox = alertBox("There is all ready a User Account registered with that Email Address.", "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
            } else {
                // Create the new account
                $password = encryptIt($_POST['password']);
                $usersName = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['usersName']);
                $joinDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $hash = md5(rand(0,1000));
                $isActive = '0';

                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
                                    INSERT INTO
                                        users(
                                            usersEmail,
                                            password,
                                            usersName,
                                            joinDate,
                                            hash,
                                            isActive
                                        ) VALUES (
                                            ?,
                                            ?,
                                            ?,
                                            ?,
                                            ?,
                                            ?
                                        )");
                $stmt->bind_param('ssssss',
                    $newEmail,
                    $password,
                    $usersName,
                    $joinDate,
                    $hash,
                    $isActive
                );
                $stmt->execute();

                // Send out the email in HTML
                require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

                $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

                $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

                //Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
                $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';


                $mail->isSMTP();                                     // Set mailer to use SMTP
                $mail->Host = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
                $mail->Username = 'looloobs';                 // SMTP username
                $mail->Password = 'passowrd';                           // SMTP password
                $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
                $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to             // TCP port to connect to

                $mail->From = 'militarypropertyproject@gmail.com';
                $mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
                $mail->addAddress('laurenrothlisberger@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
                $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');

                $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
                $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
                $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';


                if(!$mail->send()) {
                    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
                    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                } else {
                    echo 'Message has been sent';
                }

                $stmt->close();


                // Clear the Form of values
                $_POST['usersName'] = $_POST['usersEmail'] = $_POST['password'] = $_POST['passwordr'] = $_POST['captcha'] = '';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are getting a 500 Internal Server error as your title suggests, then go check the server’s error log first of all.

Comment: I admittedly don't know a lot about server logs but when I go in there this is all I see. "[01/Sep/2014:19:48:18 -0400] "POST /login.php HTTP/1.1" 500 - "http://scoutmember-milpropertyproj.rhcloud.com/login.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"

Comment: That line would be from the server’s _access_ log … the __error__ log is a different one.

Comment: Thanks, despite doing all the things they say to turn on the Error logs I can't seem to get them to show. So I guess I will have to wait until I can hear from OpenShift tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: Don't post your passwords, especially not twice!

Comment: This is the error I receive: SMTP connect() failed. Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'SMTP connect() failed.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to send via `SMTP` (the `Simple Mail Transfer Protocol`), however, you're passing in SendGrid's Web API domain as a hostname. Thus when phpmailer tries to connect to the "domain" `https://api.sendgrid.com/` it fails.

To fix this, change this line:

```
$mail->Host = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
```

To:

```
$mail->Host = 'smtp.sendgrid.net';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
```

Comment: Thanks on past php mailers I used the previous, but that was the problem.

Answer (score -2):

```
$mail->IsMail();
```

you have to use this

Comment: @Shen: You really need to pay much closer attention to the questions you are answering.